# Background screen becomes non interactive when dialog is displayed

Tags: android, android-layout

Need help with below case -

Screen has edit text when we enter text display popup dialog and display search result for entered text in background edit text.
Pop-up dialog has title text view and List view which displays search result.

When I enter first letter in edit text, pop-up dialog gets displayed but then background screen which has edit text 
becomes non interactive and I am not able to enter any text further in edit text.

Does anyone has solution for this issue? Or do I need to use different approach please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It is the intended behaviour of a dialog, to block everything in the background, while it is shown (modal dialog), so you probably need to find a different way to achieve what you want.

Have a look at the AutoCompleteTextView, this might be what you want.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView